# Configuring Hive Registry Storage for Multiple Partition

Tags: windows, registry, windows-ce, partitioning

I have edited NandUpdateLib.cpp to create 2 Nand Partitions. As a result, my system won't fully boot anymore since it can't find the registry (or event the the partition???). Although the system can boot from Nand, it gets stuck early in the process  as soon as nk bin is loaded so I can't do further diagnostics.

Aside from editing the createpartition code, is there any additional steps needed like editing a specific reg or driver?

Here are what I believe relevant registries:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\StorageManager\Profiles\MSFlash]
    "DefaultFileSystem"="FATFS"    
    "PartitionDriver"="FLASHPART.dll"
    "AutoFormat"=dword:1
    "AutoPart"=dword:1
    "AutoMount"=dword:1
    "Name"="NAND FLASH Storage"
    "Folder"="NANDFlash"
    ;"FormatExfat"=dword:1
IF SYSGEN_FSREGHIVE
    "Flags"=dword:1000
    "MountAsBootable"=dword:1
ENDIF SYSGEN_FSREGHIVE
```

I named my 2 partitions "PART00" and "PART01". I have a filesystem folder called "NANDFS".

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The system needs to know which of the partitions contains the hive, i.e.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\StorageManager\Profiles\MSFlash\Part00]
    "MountAsBootable"=dword:1
```

See also MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa914710.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa914710.aspx). The **MountAsBootable** documentation seems to imply that the hive can only be stored on the first partition.

Another thing to be aware of is that all registry entries required to load the hive must be wrapped in

```
; HIVE BOOT SECTION
    (entries)
; END HIVE BOOT SECTION
```

If you had the registry working before the NAND was partitioned then that is probably not an issue.